# Run Code Snippet: No scrollbars in preview

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, user-experience

When you run a code snippet, there is no scrollbar anymore. I do not know if there problem has to do with the console output that is being displayed (and hides part of the snippet itself).

I personally find the console output something very usefull in the code snippet, however, if it hides a part of the html output and I cannot see, or click other elements in the snippet (without clicking Full Page view), I am not sure if I would choose console output much more in the future (personally I favor it over alerts to show some information)

Is there something that can be done about this behavior? Can I choose to either hide the console, put the console on the right, or have scrollbars in both console and snippet view?

2 example questions where I have found this behavior in my own answers:

[how to get value of checked box where values are dynamiclly in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198729/how-to-get-value-of-checked-box-where-values-are-dynamiclly-in-ng-repeat/41199318#41199318)

[image: Hidden buttons + html]

Where clicking once on the show results (which outputs to the console) makes the snippet look like this (hidding the buttons)

[JavaScript - How to detect the source that changed the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089203/javascript-how-to-detect-the-source-that-changed-the-url/41090258#41090258)

[image: Completely overlapping the rendered html]

Where clicking the links that output some meta information for the user hides practically the full output view

That is a pitty because I like the snippet editor very much, and it makes it easy to demonstrate an answer in the question without having to link to other resources as jsfiddle or other resources

I am not sure if I should see it as a usability problem or a feature request